# MySQL String pattern matching - Alternatives for like

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, full-text-search, pattern-matching

MySQL like clause lets wildcard searches like `'%keyword%'` where keyword is sandwiched within the column value.

For pattern matching where the keyword contains a part of the column value and when `%keyword%` will not work, we can use `INSTR` function to do the search.

Example:

```
Column="Apple"
$keyword = "An Apple a day"
```

Here, we cannot do `Column like '%$keyword%'` to make a match but `(INSTR('$Keyword', Column)>0` would do the match.

What alternatives (regex?, fulltext search?, lucene?) do we have other than INSTR for pattern-matching such cases (examples?) ?

**Update:**

```
Column = "Golden Apple"
$keyword = "An Apple a day"
```

Even for samples like this, I would like to be able to match the $keyword with column as they have a common term "Apple".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can still use `LIKE`:

```
'%$keyword%' LIKE CONCAT('%', Column, '%')
```

Or regular expression:

```
'%$keyword%' REGEXP Column
```

Comment: if Column="Golden Apple", this will not work. If both the search term and column have some matching characters regardless of positions, it becomes an issue. I'll update my question to reflect this case.

Comment: Do you mean you want to match even `Golden Apple` with `apple pie`?

Comment: Exactly! I want to match them if they have any set of consecutive matching characters.

Comment: Even one character? Because any column with an `a` or `e` or `i` or ..., will match `Apple pie`. So, almost anything.

Comment: Possibly yes. It would match single characters as well. But an assumption we have to make is that the app using this logic would usually contain search terms which are words with more than a character in length.

Comment: From your update, it seems that full-text engines like Lucene or Solr best fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand clearly what exactly you want to do, but try this link to find the help about [pattern matching in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Are you writing a procedure,a trigger, or simply a select?

Comment: I am not concerned with triggers or procedures. Say if your requirement is to match keywords with column values like in the example of the question, how would you do it? A simple like clause is not the solution here so I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [SOUNDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) and [Natural Language](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) (using full text searches and relevance) searches.